# Back In Time recognizes old snapshots but not old data in new PC

Tags: hard-drive, backup, external-hdd, rsync, backintime

I've been using the great "Back In Time" (BIT) to backup my data HDD (/data, 4 TB, NTFS for dual boot with Windows 10) on Kubuntu 20.04 to an external HDD.

Recently, I built a new PC, installed Kubuntu 22.04 with new /home but the same host- and username, transferred the old HDD to it, and again mounted it at /data.

When I started BIT, it successfully restored the backup configuration from my old snapshots and I can see them in BIT. However, if I create a new snapshot, BIT doesn't recognize that almost everything on /data is old, and starts a full new snapshot from scratch.

How do I tell BIT that /data is still the same?

Beginner here, grateful for any help!